# How can I add this button in code using swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, button

So I'm following a tutorial, and we have to place buttons into our storyboard.

They have given us a bit of code (which I'm assuming customizes the button) which is the following:

```
Button(action: {
  print("Button pressed")
}, label: {
    Text("AC").frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
      .background(Color.blue)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .cornerRadius(40)
    .font(.title)
})
```

I'm not sure where to put this, in the view controller? When I do I get an error. Also, how would I connect this code to the button in the story board?

Thanks for the help!
ajn

Comment: That is SwiftUI code, not storyboard. What tutorial are you following?

Comment: @Sweeper You crack me up.

Comment: @Sweeper that could be the problem I chose storyboard instead of swift UI. Where would I past this code in swiftUI? (I just changed the project)

Comment: Aren't you following a tutorial? What does the tutorial use? If you got this code from the tutorial, then it's using SwiftUI, so you should put it in the `body` of a `View`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the Button outlet like this

```
    var acButton: UIButton {
    let acButton = UIButton()
    acButton.titleLabel?.text = "AC"
    acButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    acButton.tintColor = .white
    acButton.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    acButton.titleLabel?.font = .yourFont
    acButton.frame = CGRect(x: contentView.center.x,
                            y: contentView.center.y,
                            width: 80,
                            height: 80)
    return acButton
}
```

and then create function which will be called when you tap on it

```
    @objc func acButtonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button Pressed")
}
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    acButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(acButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Quick question though, how do I connect this code to the button ui in the storyboard?

Comment: this example of creating button in clean code, so you can not directly connect it to storyboard.
But try to insert all of this code into ViewController body ;)

Comment: if you want to connect it to the storyboard, You have to create it differently, go to storyboard and then open Assistant editor, then click the button on storyboard and hold ctrl and drag it to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Create an IBOutlet for the button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourButton: UIButton()
```

By assigning the button as an outlet, the button can later be used in storyboard. Now in ViewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    yourButton.setTitle("button", for: .normal)
    yourButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    yourButton.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    yourButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    yourButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    yourButton.titleLabel?.font = .yourFont
    yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFunction), for: .touchUpInside)

   // I don't know if the code below is necessary when using @IBOutlet, but I added it anyways
   view.addSubview(yourButton)
}

@objc func yourFunction{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SwiftUI view as a UIKit subview, so place it into another SwiftUI view and then you can host it using UIHostingController to add into traditional viewControllers hierarchy.

Or You can use UIButton instead.